# Alpha of two overlapping views

Tags: android, android-graphics

I'd like to know is there any solution for a problem I am facing. Here is the picture illustrating what I'll be talking about :

[image: picture]

So I have two views (`A` and `B`) that are inside `FrameLayout` and `A` is overlapping `B` (`A` is drawn above `B`). `A`'s background is white color with some alpha component and `B`'s foreground is white color with exact the same alpha component as `A`'s background. Is it possible to make space where those views overlaps (marked as `AxB` in the picture) to have exactly the same alpa as those two views? Right now it is "whiter".

Comment: Here is what you are looking for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: @Dummy How do I apply this? I was trying `background/foreground = ColorDrawable(color).apply { setColorFilter(color, porterDuffMode) }` with every possible combination and it didn't work.

Comment: Just read the API docs for usage